# Error "Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" on parameter in my fuction that clearly is an array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print multidimensional array in C, but I fail to do so after manipulating it.

The function:

```
void vypisArray(float arrayX[],int rozmeryX[]){

     for (int i=0;i<rozmeryX[0];i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < rozmeryX[1]; j++) {
            printf("%f ",arrayX[i][j]);     //line 40 --error here
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");


}
```

and the usage:

```
vypisArray(arrayX,rozmeryX);
```

Expected output is basically printout of  any multidimensional array with proper formatting into console.

**Did i missed something?** ,**There might be confusion on my part  shooed I use pointers to reference my array rather then just pass it into my function as plain multidimention array parameter?**

Here is the error log:

```
    In function 'vypisArray':
40  35      [Error] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
            In function 'skenujArray':
62  25      [Error] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
    In function 'main':
137 4       [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'skenujArray' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
55  6       [Note] expected 'float *' but argument is of type 'float (*)[(sizetype)(rozmeryA[1])]'
138 4       [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'skenujArray' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
55  6       [Note] expected 'float *' but argument is of type 'float (*)[(sizetype)(rozmeryB[1])]'
```

**Edit : problem is fixed , i was confused on how to specify multidim arrays in C functions.**

```
void vypisArray(int rozmeryX[],float arrayX[][rozmeryX[1]]) // code works
```

Comment: Your parameter that is "clearly an array" is, in fact, not an array, but a pointer.

Comment: Can you show us how you call the function, i.e. the definition of data that you wanted to pass as array ?

Comment: @Christophe problem fixed, I tought that array[] will be enought to specify that i work with multidimensional array,cause in definition of my function i had error when i did [][]  (kinda dumb to think i know) bud im new to c,so i specified even further and commented out my definition of function prototype and everything works as it shoud :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float arrayX[]
```

that's not a multidimensional array, thats just an array of floats

Comment: In fact, since it's declared as a parameter, it's a pointer, not an array. (The `[]` indexing operator applies to arrays.)

Comment: @Keith Nicholas I know keith, any idea why i had error when i was defining my function with parameter arrayX[][]? Thats the reason i used normal array and not multi dim, i removed definition and just went for function declaration only, where i further specified that i work with multi dim array.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access a single dimensional array in two-dimensional way.
instead of doing

```
printf("%f ",arrayX[i][j]);
```

do

```
printf("%f ",arrayX[i]);
```